# How To read Block of text in a text file

Tags: c#, linq, console-application, text-files, streamreader

I have a file in which i have to read text between startscriptexpression$ and Finish scriptExpression$, and also read between startupdatedescription$ and startupdatedescription$[[image: Test.txt1]

The problem is that i want to re write the code in a cleaner format.

```
My Code:

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace Vesrion
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string path = @"C:\Users\Development\Desktop\Read\Test.txt";
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(path))
            {
                var textInBetween = new List<string>();
                var ListOFDescription = new List<string>();
                string NewString = "";

                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    var line = reader.ReadLine();
                  //Reads First line,
                    switch (line)
                    {
                        case "StartScriptExpression$":
                            continue;
                        case "FinishScriptExpression$":
                            if (line.Contains("FinishScriptExpression$"))
                            {
                                line = "";
                            }
                            string Something = string.Join("", textInBetween);
                            textInBetween = line.Split(',').ToList();
                            string[] lines = Something.Split(
                             new string[] { Environment.NewLine },
                                 StringSplitOptions.None);
                            foreach (var S in lines)
                            {
                                ListOFDescription.Add(S);
                                Console.WriteLine(S);
                            }

                            NewString += ListOFDescription;
                           
                        break;
                        case "StartUpdateDescription$":
                            //Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
                            continue;
                        case "FinishUpdateDescription$":
                           // Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
                            continue;
                        default:
                            textInBetween.Add(line);
                            //Console.WriteLine(line);
                            break;
                           
                    }
                }

            }

        }

    }
}
```

- Text inside start and finish expression must be in a list of string array.
- text inside startupdatedescription and finishupdatedescription must be in a string.

  .

Comment: Not sure, but with few LINQ methods and Regex seems work as expected. Try here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/pxBAMv

Comment: Great seems to be working,but i want sql commands from foreach to be in a single string
E.G [0] create table.....
      [1]create table.....
      [2]Alter table registration...............
      [3]Adding auto number...................

Comment: You want concat 4 strings (commands) into 1 string?

Comment: Final output must be as follows between startscriptexpression and finishscriptexpression in a list:
[0]- CREATE TABLE [CompanyBranch]([CompanyBranchID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) .....
[1]- CREATE TABLE [CompanyBranchDept]([CompanyBranchDeptID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) ..
[2]-ALTER TABLE REGISTRATION_FILE_REFERENCING ADD BranchLink bit
[3]-ALTER TABLE EASY_FILE ADD Remarks varchar(250)

Comment: I want to concat everything start and end expression into 1 string.

Comment: So what the problem? `string.Join(" ", sqlCommand)` join each part of 1 command. To concat them all just join them all - `string.Join(" ", sqlCommands.Select(sqlCommand => string.Join(" ", sqlCommand)));`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239733/discussion-between-tshepo-kgetinti-and-auditive).

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is using regular expression https://dotnetfiddle.net/pxBAMv

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).